# Exclude files from code inspection tool in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lint

Android code inspection for html files gives an error "Start tag has wrong closing tag" and "Closing tag matches nothing " but everything is fine in that particular html file.

I looked around in Android Studio and inspection settings as such but not been able to permanently disable inspection of some files (like html files in this case). I was wondering if we could have any config setting in build.gradle file just like the custom lint config file or if there is any other way to edit inspection settings.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you post the html file?

Comment: Here is the sample html file: `<!--suppress HtmlUnknownTag -->
<div style="padding:0px 8px 8px 8px;">

<p><b>...........</b></p>
    
<p><strong>Introduction</strong></p>
    
<p>............</br>
    
<ul>
    <li> ........</li>
    <li>..........</li>
 </ul></p> 
</div>`

Comment: i have all the start and end tags properly written but if i introduce for example a </br> in the paragraph, it complains..which is weird

Comment: I tried changing the inspection settings locally and all. But wouldn't that be local to my machine?. I want to have the configuration setting such that it could be checked in to code base just like we do **lintconfig file "filename.xml"** so when some one else does inspect, then these false positive errors should not show up..

Comment: It looks like you mistakenly typed the `<br />` (or `<br>`?)as `</br>`, so the code inspector thinks you're trying to close the `<p>` tag with a `</br>`.  I don't know the answer to your question, but I think fixing your html would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

you are probably putting the html file in the wrong place
Are you sure that your file is in this directory? `YourApplicationName\app\src\main\assets`